# Launch native app when link shared in Twitter clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

How to open a native app if installed or app store page if not installed, when a link shared in Twitter was clicked. I am sharing the link in twitter with card type as 'summary_large_image'. 
I am setting the following meta tags in the web page which will be loaded when the shared link was clicked.

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content=“appUrlScheme://“>
<meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="appUrlScheme://">
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content=“123456”>
<meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content=“123456”>
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content=“AppName”>
<meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content=“AppName”>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="og:image" content=“image url“>
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content=“image url”>
<meta property="og:title" content=“Test Title“>
<meta name="twitter:title" content=“Test Title“>
<meta property="og:description" content=“Test Description”>
<meta name="twitter:description" content=“Test Description“>
<meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US">
<meta property="al:web:url" content=“app website URL”>
<meta property="og:image" content=“image URL“>
```

Please provide me the steps to launch the app when shared link was clicked. 
Currently the in-app browser of Twitter gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to implement deep linking to app for card type of "summary_large_image" and "summary".